# Как сделать такую штуку в Студии, даже на знаю как обозвать. Слайд, наверное?

Tags: android

Когда пальчиком по экрану проводишь и поворачивается какой-либо объект на экране? Не знаю даже как загуглить. Подскажите, как такая дичь называется? Вот на пикче тип пальцем задает отклонение прицепа. Такое интересует. Или как сам объект так потаскать, но чтобы он не за пальцем тянулся, а оставался на заданной траектории[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Поворот чего-либо относительно его `"центра тяжести"`, на данной пикче `"цт"` у прицепа `"top-center"`.
(Какой вопрос, такой и ответ)